# Angular. Reactive form two way data binding

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

After data loaded i call reInit form. After manipulate with data from html template class didn't updated and at this moment i use this:

```
Object.assign(this.customer, this.customerForm.getRawValue());
```

But I know that this is bad solution, and each every key and update data by conditions isn't good way. Maby some easy way exists?

I have some class, for Example:

```
export class Customer {
    id: number|null = null;
    short_name: string|null = null;
    full_name: string|null = null;
    contacts: Contact[] = [];
    constructor(data?: Foo) { /* ... */ }
}
export class Contact {
    id: number|null = null;
    name: string|null = null;
    general: boolean;
    emails: {email: string|null, general: boolean}[];
    phones: {phone: string|null, general: boolean}[];
}
```

for create all data empty, for existed Customer some filds filled.

now create a form:

```
  // convenience getters for easy access to form fields
  get controls(): {[key: string]: AbstractControl} { return this.customerForm.controls; }
  get contacts(): FormArray { return this.controls.contacts as FormArray; }

  emails(contact: any): FormArray  { return contact.controls.emails as FormArray; }
  phones(contact: any): FormArray  { return contact.controls.phones as FormArray; }

private initForm(customer?: Customer) {
    this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      short_name: [customer?.short_name, Validators.required],
      full_name: [customer?.full_name, Validators.required],
      user_id: [customer?.user_id, Validators.required],
      site: [customer?.site],
      contacts: new FormArray([])
    });
    this.customer.contacts.map(c => this.addContact(c));
  }
private addContact(c: Contact): FormGroup {
    const contactFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [c?.id],
      name: [c?.name, [
        Validators.required,
        CustomerContactValidator.createContact,
        CustomerContactValidator.onlyOneGeneralEmail,
        CustomerContactValidator.onlyOneGeneralPhone,
      ]],
      general: [c?.general],
      position: [c?.position],
      comment: [c?.comment],
      emails: new FormArray([]),
      phones: new FormArray([])
    });
    this.contacts.push(contactFormGroup);
    c.emails.map(ed => this.addContactEmail(contactFormGroup, ed));
    c.phones.map(pd => this.addContactPhone(contactFormGroup, pd));
    return contactFormGroup;
  }



  private addContactEmail(contactFormGroup: FormGroup, ed: ContactEmail, contactFormGroupIndex: number|null = null): void {
    const emails = contactFormGroup.controls.emails as FormArray;
    if (emails) {
      const contactEmailFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        type: [ed?.type],
        general: [ed?.general],
        email: [ed?.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
      });
      emails.push(contactEmailFormGroup);
      if (contactFormGroupIndex !== null) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById(`email-${contactFormGroupIndex}-${emails.length-1}`)?.focus();
        }, 50);
      }
      this.afterManipulateWithContactContacts(contactFormGroup);
    }
  }

  private addContactPhone(contactFormGroup: FormGroup, pd: ContactPhone, contactFormGroupIndex: number|null = null): void {
    const phones = contactFormGroup.controls.phones as FormArray;
    if (phones) {
      const contactPhoneFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        type: [pd?.type],
        general: [pd?.general],
        phone: [pd?.phone, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(PHONE_PATTERN)]]
      });
      phones.push(contactPhoneFormGroup);
      if (contactFormGroupIndex !== null) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          document.getElementById(`phone-${contactFormGroupIndex}-${phones.length-1}`)?.focus();
        }, 50);
      }
      this.afterManipulateWithContactContacts(contactFormGroup);
    }
  }
```

and html:

```
<form class="customer-form" [formGroup]="customerForm">
<ng-container *ngFor="let contact of contacts.controls; let i = index" >
      <div [formGroup]="$any(contact)" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-md="row">
        <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="20" fxFlex.gt-lg="15" [ngClass.gt-md]="'pr-2'">
          <mat-checkbox
            [ngClass.gt-md]="'mr-2'"
            [ngClass.lt-lg]="'mr-1'"
            formControlName="general"
            (change)="changeGeneralContact($any(contact))"
          ></mat-checkbox>
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" style="width: calc(100% - 24px)">
            <input formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="ФИО" type="text">
            <mat-error *ngIf="contact.get('name')?.hasError('required')">Заполните <strong>ФИО</strong></mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="contact.get('name')?.hasError('createContact')">Добавьте <strong>email</strong> или <strong>телефон</strong></mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="contact.get('name')?.hasError('onlyOneGeneralEmail')">Только <strong>один email</strong> может быть основным</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="contact.get('name')?.hasError('onlyOneGeneralPhone')">Только <strong>один телефон</strong> может быть основным</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-lg="20" [ngClass.gt-md]="'px-2'">
          <div *ngFor="let email of emails($any(contact)).controls; let ei = index">
            <div [formGroup]="$any(email)" class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <mat-checkbox
                [ngClass.gt-md]="'mr-2'"
                [ngClass.lt-lg]="'mr-1'"
                formControlName="general"
                (change)="changeContactGeneralSubContact($any(contact), $any(email), contactSubType.email)"
              ></mat-checkbox>
              <crm-email-edit [formGroup]="$any(email)" floatLabel="never" style="width: calc(100% - 60px)"></crm-email-edit>
              <button
                mat-icon-button
                matTooltip="Удалить email"
                aria-label="Удалить email"
                (click)="removeContactEmailContact(i, ei, $any(contact))"
              >
                <mat-icon color="warn">delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              mat-icon-button
              color="primary"
              [matTooltip]="'Добавить email'"
              (click)="createContactEmailContact($any(contact), i)"
            >
              <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-md="25" fxFlex.gt-lg="20"  [ngClass.gt-md]="'px-2'">
          <div *ngFor="let phone of phones($any(contact)).controls; let pi = index">
            <div [formGroup]="$any(phone)">
              <mat-checkbox
                [ngClass.gt-md]="'mr-2'"
                [ngClass.lt-lg]="'mr-1'"
                formControlName="general"
                (change)="changeContactGeneralSubContact($any(contact), $any(phone), contactSubType.phone)"
              ></mat-checkbox>
              <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
                <input [id]="'phone-'+i+'-'+pi" formControlName="phone" matInput placeholder="Телефон" type="number">
                <mat-error *ngIf="phone.get('phone')?.hasError('required')">Заполните <strong>Телефон</strong> или удалите</mat-error>
                <mat-error *ngIf="phone.get('phone')?.hasError('pattern')"><strong>Телефон</strong> указан не верно</mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
              <button
                mat-icon-button
                matTooltip="Удалить телефон"
                aria-label="Удалить телефон"
                (click)="removeContactPhoneContact(i, pi, $any(contact))"
              >
                <mat-icon color="warn">delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button
              mat-icon-button
              color="primary"
              [matTooltip]="'Добавить телефон'"
              (click)="createContactPhoneContact($any(contact), i)"
            >
              <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="10" fxFlex.gt-md="5" [ngClass.gt-md]="'px-2'">
          <button
            mat-mini-fab
            color="warn"
            matTooltip="Удалить контакт"
            aria-label="Удалить контакт"
            (click)="removeContact(i)"
          >
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
    
    <div>
      <button mat-fab (click)="createContact()" aria-label="Добавить контакт" color="primary">
        <mat-icon>person_add</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you saying you get value from, this.customerForm.getRawValue() and then manipulate it but it does not update the values on the form?

Comment: no, using getRawValue isn't good solution. Good - reactive form on change some value - update class propery value without any coding

Comment: Sorry i don’t understand what your orignal problem is?

Comment: simple 2 way binding with using reactive forms and data from some class without ngModel for each row/subscription for value changes and magic with using getRawValue()

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct two-way model binding in reactive form, but in a sense has two way form binding.

1. You provide value to  `ABC: formControls(['My value'])`
2. ABC controller can be updated from controller or HTML template.

a. In HTML it will be updated by user.

b. In component.ts you can update it by controllers only  `ABC.PatchValue or setValue.`

you can get all the value from  `getRawValue()` or `.value`, but you cant manipulate these values to update the form directly.